# ¿Como no alterar la integridad del formulario al cambiar la estructura del JSON?

Tags: javascript, html

La cuestión es, que ahora mismo tengo un `formulario` en el cual, al editar cualquier cosa, para en formato JSON los valores a un textarea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito hacer es que, al alterar el resultado del `JSON`, no se rompa el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaría alguna forma de poder sostener la estructura del formulario para seguir generando el JSON. Inserto aquí el código del programa:

```js
class formLOGOSTariff{

   initL(){
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;
      var temForm    = document.querySelector("#temp-form").innerHTML;

      let foorm = document.createElement('div');
         foorm.innerHTML = temForm;
         document.body.appendChild(foorm);

      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");
      console.log(contentForm);

      let card = document.createElement("div");
         card.innerHTML = temCard
         contentForm.appendChild(card);

      let power = document.createElement("div");
         power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
         energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

            card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
            card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);

   }

   static addPower(el)   {
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

      let power = document.createElement("div");
         power.innerHTML = temPower;
            el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
               return power;

   }

   static addEnergy(el)   {
      var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

      let energy = document.createElement('div');
         energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
            el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);
               return energy;
   }

   static addFrm() {
      var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
    
      var cont = document.querySelector('#content-form')
      let frm = document.createElement('div');


         frm.innerHTML = tmp;
         cont.appendChild(frm);
         formLOGOSTariff.addPower(frm);
         formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(frm);
            return frm;
   }

   static sndFrm()   {
      var jotason = [];

      document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            let obj = {
               title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
            };

            let power = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.type=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var ob = power[index]||{};
               ob.value=inpt.value;
               power[index]=ob;
            });

            let energy = {};
            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.type=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
               var oj = energy[index]||{};
               oj.value=inpt.value;
               energy[index]=oj;
            });

            obj.power = power;
            obj.energy = energy;
            jotason.push(obj);

      })
      var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);

      document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
   }

   static sndTo(){
      document.querySelector('#content-form').innerHTML='';
      
      let pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;

      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{

            let formDv = formLOGOSTariff.addFrm();
            formDv.querySelector(".container-power").innerHTML='';

               for(let n1  in form.power){
                  (pow=>{
                     let power = formLOGOSTariff.addPower(formDv);
                     
                     power.querySelector("[name=t_power]").value=pow.type;
                     power.querySelector("[name=v_power]").value=pow.value;
                  })(form.power[n1])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".container-energy").innerHTML='';

               for(let n2 in form.energy){
                  (eng=>{
                     let energy = formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(formDv);

                     energy.querySelector("[name=t_energy]").value=eng.type;
                     energy.querySelector("[name=v_energy]").value=eng.value;
                  })(form.energy[n2])
               }

            formDv.querySelector(".name_tarif").value=form.title;
           
         })(dat[n])
      }
   }

   static delFrm(){
if(confirm('¿Quieres borrarlo?')){
   var nm = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD").length -1;
      var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("templatecARD")[nm];
      if (nm > 0){
         cont.remove()
      } else {
         //alert('No puedes borrar el último');
      }
   }}
/*
   static txtTrnsm(){
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("name_tarif").value);
   }
   */
}



window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
   var nomVre = new formLOGOSTariff();
   nomVre.initL();
});

// Script sin meter en el class

/*
   window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
      
         // metemos las estructuras de los templates gracias a innerHTML dentro de variables
      var temCard    = document.querySelector("#temp-card").innerHTML;
      var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;
      var temEnergy  = document.querySelector("#temp-energy").innerHTML;

         // hacemos una seleccion del div #content-form
      var contentForm   = document.querySelector("#content-form");

         // Creamos los div corresponidentes asignandoles a cada uno
         // su template concreta
      let card = document.createElement("div");
      card.innerHTML = temCard
      contentForm.appendChild(card);
      let power = document.createElement("div");
      power.innerHTML = temPower;

      let energy = document.createElement("div");
      energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;

         // Metemos dentro de los container los hijos power y energy
         // anteriormente definidos
      card.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
      card.querySelector(".container-energy").appendChild(energy);
   });

//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_POWER

function addPower(el)   {
   var temPower   = document.querySelector("#temp-power").innerHTML;

   let power = document.createElement("div");
   power.innerHTML = temPower;
   el.querySelector(".container-power").appendChild(power);
   return power;

}
//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
function addEnergy(el)   {
   var temEnergy  =  document.querySelector('#temp-energy').innerHTML;

   let energy = document.createElement('div');
   energy.innerHTML = temEnergy;
   el.querySelector('.container-energy').appendChild(energy);
   return energy;
}

//       BTN ADD TEMPLATE FORM
function addFrm() {
   var tmp = document.querySelector('#temp-card').innerHTML;
 
   var cont = document.querySelector('#content-form')
   let frm = document.createElement('div');


   frm.innerHTML = tmp;
   cont.appendChild(frm);
   addPower(frm);
   addEnergy(frm);
   return frm;
}

function reReload(){
   location.reload();
}

//    BTN LECTURA VALORES INPUT

function sndFrm()   {
      // Hacer una variable con formato JSON vacio

   var jotason = [];
      // Seleccionar TODOS los templatecARD con el bucle forEach
   document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

            // Metemos dentro de la variable obj la estructura del title
            // asignando a title el valor del input .name_tarif
         let obj = {
            title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
         };
         // power
         let power = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.type=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.value=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });

         // energy
         let energy = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.type=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.value=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         obj.power = power;
         obj.energy = energy;
         jotason.push(obj);

   })


      // Hacer un string del JSON jotason [fil:69]
   var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);
      // Meter dentro del textarea con id txtare el valor 
      // de jotason [fil:69]
   document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
}

function sndTo(){
      document.querySelector('#content-form').innerHTML='';
      let pJsn = document.getElementById('txtare').value;
     // console.log(pJsn);
      var dat  = JSON.parse(pJsn);
      for(let n in dat){
         (form=>{


            let formDv = addFrm();
            formDv.querySelector(".container-power").innerHTML='vacio';
            for(let n1  in form.power){
               (pow=>{
                  let power = addPower(formDv);
                  
                  power.querySelector("[name=t_power]").value=pow.type;
                  power.querySelector("[name=v_power]").value=pow.value;
               })(form.power[n1])

            }
            formDv.querySelector(".container-energy").innerHTML='vacio';
            for(let n2 in form.energy){
               (eng=>{
                  let energy = addEnergy(formDv);

                  energy.querySelector("[name=t_energy]").value=eng.type;
                  energy.querySelector("[name=v_energy]").value=eng.value;
               })(form.energy[n2])
            }
            //form.power.forEach(pow=>{
               //addPower(formDv);
            //});


            formDv.querySelector(".name_tarif").value=form.title;
           
         })(dat[n])
      }
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template id="temp-card">
 
    <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >

        <label>Tarifa</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
        
        <div>

            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addPower(this.parentNode)">+</button>

        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addEnergy(this.parentNode)">+</button>

        </div>

    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power" >
        <label style="text-transform: capitalize;">PRECIOS POR POTENCIA</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="t_power" style="width:40px" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_power" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-energy">
    <div class="box-energy" >
        <label>PRECIOS POR ENERGÍA</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="t_energy"  name="t_energy" style="width:40px" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
            <input type="text" class="v_energy"  name="v_energy" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="">
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->


    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<template id="temp-form">
    <form method="post">

        <div id="content-form">

        </div>
            
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.addFrm()">+</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.delFrm()">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->


    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
<div class="jsn_edit">
<textarea id="txtare" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" onkeyup="formLOGOSTariff.sndTo()"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="formLOGOSTariff.sndTo()">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por no alterar te refieres a que el `texarea` no sea editable?

Comment: No, sino pondría un conteneditable=false
Me refiero a que si, al borrar todo el JSON como en la segunda imagen, desaparezca el formulario

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que valides si lo que contiene el `textarea`  es un JSON para continuar o no las demas funciones, asi ya no se borrara nada. Para validar encontre lo siguiente https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204

Comment: Intenta hacerlo de esa forma

Comment: Vale perfecto, ahora enseguida lo pruebo, muchas gracias!!!